# API Curl Options

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to send a cURL request using PHP with the following options:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://news-api.apple.com/channels/485ae91a-2212-4276-9d07-4f6a9dc82da7/articles");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'POST';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: HHMAC; key={$key}; signature={$api_signature}; date={$date}';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

My problem is my variables are not showing up as their values -- like this:

```
Authorization: HHMAC; key={$key}; signature={$api_signature}; date={$date}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: PHP variables aren't expanded in single-quoted strings - change that line to use double quotes

Comment: @iainn that should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Change that line to use double quotes, PHP variables aren't expanded in single-quoted strings

```
$headers[] = "Authorization: HHMAC; key={$key}; signature={$api_signature}; date={$date}";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **double-quotes**, so the variables can expand, i.e.:

```
$headers[] = "Authorization: HHMAC; key={$key}; signature={$api_signature}; date={$date}";
```

Note:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` is useless, because it's included by default when you use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);`